# Stored Procedure with two input params and multiple matches and create view with in

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not much strong in SQL, so looking for some help.

First I am looking for suggestion for the best way to implement this logic in SQL and then some sample code to implement.

My portal is going to connect Students and Training Providers.

Students: Select what courses (multiple) they want, type of delivery (online, class room), Industry(domain) to which the course to be targeted more, Location Preference.

Training Providers: Select what courses offering (so one record for each course), offering locations, type of delivery for each course, industries (multiple) it is targeting.

When student login:
I would like to create SP which in turn create view to store the matched records of the Training Providers data which matches that student needs of that StudentID, CourseID passed to SP

I have created the following sp ( but not included create view part as I am not sure how to do this)

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TPsMatched2StuCourse]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StuID int,
@CourseID int

AS
BEGIN
    Select TP.MemID,TP.PastExp,SN.DeliveryType,SN.LocPref,SN.Industry,SC.CourseID from 
tbl_TrainingProvider as TP , tbl_StuCourses as SC, tbl_StuNeeds SN
where SN.CourseID = @CourseID and SN.StuID = @StuID and
SN.DeliveryType in (TP.DeliveryMode) and 
SN.LocPref IN (TP.LocOffering) and
SN.Industry IN (TP.Industries)

END

---   exec sp_ELsMatched2EntProp 1, 1
```

Why I need to put the data is as follows:

Assume the data is stored in that dynamic view and that would be bind to datagrid. Student then select interested TPs. Then only contact details would be shared to each other and this cannot be reveresed. So I would put this interested data in another table later. Every time data changes, hence the matches. Student can change some of his/her needs or new TPs join etc so view to be temparory.

when I executed this using above command, I am not getting data though it matches few records. What is wrong I am doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You first need to stop using implict syntax, it is a very poor programming practice that was been replaced with something better in 1992.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting expected results because you filter out too many records in `WHERE`( I'm talking about this part : `SN.DeliveryType in (TP.DeliveryMode) and 
SN.LocPref IN (TP.LocOffering) and SN.Industry IN (TP.Industries)`). I'd recommend to use `JOIN ... ON` instead of specifying all tables in `FROM` and join condition in `WHERE`. I'm not sure what you want exactly, but I believe you are looking for

```
FROM tbl_StuNeeds SN 
LEFT JOIN tbl_TrainingProvider as TP ON (TP.DeliveryMode = SN.DeliveryType AND 
  SN.LocPref = TP.LocOffering AND TP.Industries = SN.Industry)
WHERE SN.CourseID = @CourseID and SN.StuID = @StuID
```

Also, there is no join conditions in your code for `tbl_StuCourses as SC` which results in cross-join.

Finally, why do you need a stored procedure at all? From what I see in your example, a table-valued function will work better:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].getTPsMatched2StuCourse(@StuID INT,@CourseID INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
  Select .... ;
```

Comment: I agreed with you up to the function part. A table valued function would get you nothing that the stored proc would not get you unless you intended to later join to other tables and add more information.

Comment: @HLGEM: I still think that inline table-valued function is a better choice in this case  . Surely, stored procedure can also do all this stuff also, I just don't see anything (such as data modification, dynamic execution, etc ) that requires stored procedure, not a function/view